# Laravel 3.x - Auto detect Routes

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-3

I'm building a CMS and trying to use a better approach when it comes to the routes. Let's say I have a "pages" controller and the following methods: "create", "edit" and "delete". The URIs for them would be like this:

```
admin/pages/create
admin/pages/edit
admin/pages/delete
```

I could hardcode the routes and everything would be fine, but It will be a mess in no time. I've searched a lot and found the code below:

```php
Route::any('admin/(.*)', array('defaults' => 'index', 'uses' => 'admin.METHOD@(:1)'));
```

The idea is to detect the method from the URL and replace it in the "admin.METHOD@". The code would handle the request and direct it to the  correct controller method and I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you can do this in Laravel 3 but there are a few gotchas that you need to be aware of. First this is how it might look.

```php
Route::any('admin/(:any)/(:any)', 'admin.(:1)@(:2)');
```

That would match a URI of `yourapp.dev/admin/pages/create` and route it to the `get_create` method on the `Admin_Pages_Controller` controller.

The first thing you need to be aware of here is when there are hyphens in your URI. You could end up with `Admin_User-accounts_Controller` because Laravel doesn't do any of that detection. In these cases it might be easier to use `Controller::call()` in the route.

```php
Route::any('admin/(:any)/(:any)', function($controller, $method)
{
    return Controller::call("{$controller}@{$method}");
});
```

At the moment that is the same as the earlier example. You'd need to do any replacement and studly casing to the variables. You could also take that example by making the method optional and reverting to a default method such as `index`.

Basically what you're trying to achieve is resourceful routing, which is handled a lot cleaner in Laravel 4. I did a quick search of the Laravel 3 bundle repository and came up with [Routely](https://github.com/JonoB/Flare-Routes). From the looks of this bundle it does a lot of the heavy lifting for you and is quite customizable.

Answer (score 0):

"The Controller::detect method simply returns an array of all of the controllers defined for the application." - Laravel 3 docs

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Comment: I strongly urge people to avoid using this method as the order of the detected controllers can vary from system to system, this often results in unexpected behavior, including some routes throwing 404s.

Comment: I agree with you, I believe either of our other solutions are the best approaches but I know people like to have their options. Just though I'd drop some additional knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should handle this restfully and have different routes per HTTP verb (request method). From there, maybe you just send all the traffic through a single controller.

```
// Create
Route::post('admin/(:any)', 'your_controller@(:1)');

// Edit
Route::put('admin/(:any)', 'your_controller@(:1)');

// Delete
Route::delete('admin/(:any)', 'your_controller@(:1)');
```

From here, your controller can define methods for all the different types of things you want to handle. Such as post_pages(), put_modules(), delete_entries(), etc.